# Creating an onClick event

Tags: javascript, velo

I'm very new to coding so let me say sorry if anything is unclear or if my existing code is confusing for you.

I have a website that let people search for restaurants using checkboxes, built with Wix. The way the code is set up right now, **as soon as the user clicks on an alternative** (let's say the check city "New York") **the page updates immediately**.

What I **want** is a Search Button that triggers the filtering event so to speak. So that when they check "New York" nothing happens until they click "Search".

Here's the code:

```js
$w.onReady(function() {

});

//Restaurant filter

export function filterPlaces() {
  let city = [];
  let type = [];
  let vibe = [];
  let sunshine = [];

  // Get the indexes of all the checkboxes checked in that group
  let cityOptions = $w("#cityGroupBox").selectedIndices
  let typeOptions = $w('#typeGroupBox').selectedIndices
  let vibeOptions = $w('#vibeGroupBox').selectedIndices
  let sunshineOptions = $w('#sunshineGroupBox').selectedIndices
  let filter = wixData.filter();

  // Next, loop through the checked items and add each field to the array and apply filter
  if (cityOptions.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cityOptions.length; i++) {
      city.push($w('#cityGroupBox').options[cityOptions[i]].value);
    }
  }
  if (city.length > 0) {
    filter = filter.hasSome("stad", city); //The "city" is a reference to the FiledKey in the database
  }

  if (typeOptions.length > 0) {
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < typeOptions.length; i2++) {
      type.push($w('#typeGroupBox').options[typeOptions[i2]].value);
    }
  }
  if (type.length > 0) {
    filter = filter.hasSome("typ", type);
  }

  if (vibeOptions.length > 0) {
    for (var i3 = 0; i3 < vibeOptions.length; i3++) {
      vibe.push($w('#vibeGroupBox').options[vibeOptions[i3]].value);
    }
  }
  if (vibe.length > 0) {
    filter = filter.hasSome("bstFr", vibe);
  }

  if (sunshineOptions.length > 0) {
    for (var i4 = 0; i4 < sunshineOptions.length; i4++) {
      sunshine.push($w('#sunshineGroupBox').options[sunshineOptions[i4]].value);
    }
  }
  if (sunshine.length > 0) {
    filter = filter.hasSome("soltagg", sunshine);
  }

  $w("#dataset1").setFilter(filter)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("count after", $w("#dataset1").getTotalCount());
    })

    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  $w('#resetButton').onClick(function() {
    $w('#cityGroupBox').value = undefined
    $w('#typeGroupBox').value = undefined
    $w('#vibeGroupBox').value = undefined
    $w('#sunshineGroupBox').value = undefined

    $w('#dataset1').setFilter(wixData.filter())
  });
}
```

Any ideas on where and how to implement this onClick event?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Bump: Any idea on how to implement this?